# How do I translate this SHA function in Java to an equivalent in Ruby?

Tags: java, ruby, sha1, encryption

I have this algorithm in Java to store passwords in database. I'd like to re-write my application in Ruby on Rails, so I need the same algorithm to compare hashed passwords. What's the Ruby equivalent of this algorithm?

```
public static String encrypt(String password) {
    MessageDigest md;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8")); // step 3
        byte raw[] = md.digest(); // step 4
        String hash = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(raw); // step 5
        return hash; // step 6
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return null;
}
```

Just for testing purpose, the "teste123" password generates this hash in my Java version:
PQ87ndys7DDEAIxeAw5sE6R4y08=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you read this, read [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386978/how-do-i-translate-this-sha-function-in-java-to-an-equivalent-in-ruby/1386987#1386987) about hashing.

Then:

```
import java.security.*;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import java.io.*;
public class test {
  public static String encrypt(String password) {
    MessageDigest md;
    try {
      md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
      md.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8")); // step 3
      byte raw[] = md.digest(); // step 4
      String hash = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(raw); // step 5
      return hash; // step 6
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(encrypt("my password"));
  }
}
```

This outputs

> ovj3+hlaCAoipokEHaqPIET58zY=

In Ruby:

```
require 'digest/sha1'
require 'base64'
Base64.b64encode Digest::SHA1.digest('my password')
```

also outputs

> ovj3+hlaCAoipokEHaqPIET58zY=

Comment: I get a "\n" with Base64.b64encode Digest::SHA1.digest('my password'):
=> "ovj3+hlaCAoipokEHaqPIET58zY=\n"

Comment: Is this seriously a problem? It's not like \n is a valid Base64 character; you can strip it out, yes?

Comment: require 'digest/sha1'
require 'base64'
Base64.b64encode(Digest::SHA1.digest('my password')).chomp

Answer (score 2):

Before you go *any* further, stop what you're doing and read this Coding Horror article: [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000953.html).

Using a plain hash, with no salt, to encode passwords is nearly as bad as not using any hashing at all.

Comment: You are right! It was a mistake of 4 years ago. But I can't restore the already stored passwords from the database, can I? I will add a salt, but I still need to know how to do it in Ruby.

Comment: Fair enough, I was afraid it might be a legacy system issue. In general, you can't directly restore the already-stored passwords, except perhaps by using a rainbow table attack (a lot of work for little benefit really). One approach might be to present your users with: "Hi! Your password has expired. Please update your password before proceeding." and store the current password encoding mechanism in your database (so you know who has updated and who hasn't).

Comment: Another option would be re-hash the already hashed password with a salt, something like this: new_hash(old_hash(password), salt) - and store all password like this

Comment: Right, good idea. I just came back to this question to add that note, and found you beat me to it!